# Does VNC allow me to connect to another computer if the computer is on another wifi network?

Tags: vnc, vncserver

I'm trying to connect to a friend's computer on a different WiFi network using VNC, and I was wondering if that would work?

Comment: Yes, if you have a path to the network, eg by using a dynamic DNS (if he doesn't have a fixed IP) and opening a port (default 5900) on his router.

Comment: Depends if the wifi network (SSID), is on the name network as the others SSIDs?  Are they isolated?  Bridge Mode? NAT?  Do they receive IPs over the LAN? If NAT mode  clients cannot communicate with each other, but they may communicate with devices on the wired LAN if the SSID firewall settings permit.